# I can't get my ruby on the rails to properly import bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I keep trying to

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

in `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss`, however, when I try to I get the error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
Load paths:
  /Users/SimonFekete/environment/course_cat/app/assets/config
```

When I comment out `@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';` it works though.

I appreciate any help and please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this gem in your gemfile.
`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'`

Also, Have you **restarted the server** after installing the gem.

If it doesn't work out, remove `gem 'bootstrap'` and/or `gem 'sass-rails'`, if you have any of them in your gemfile

Comment: I have gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7' and neither of those other two in my gemfile

Comment: I'm now getting this error 
'couldn't find file 'popper' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/SimonFekete/environment/course_cat/app/assets/config'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your application.js :

//= require bootstrap-sprockets

Remember, always put //= require filename above //= require_tree .